# Can the visNetwork (R) output save as vector pdf file?

Tags: r, visnetwork

I've tried

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, group = c("B", "A", "B"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(2,3))

visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visExport(type = "pdf")
```

and unfortunately, the pdf generated doesn't contain a vectorial image of my network but a bad quality raster image.

How can I get a high-quality vector pdf file?

Comment: seems to be something that has not been solved yet: https://github.com/datastorm-open/visNetwork/issues/204